# Prevent Null Check in MapStruct

Tags: mapstruct

Mapper

```
@Mapping(target="subjectName", source="courseName")
Target map(Source source);
```

MapStruct generated method

```
public Target map(Source source) {
        if ( source == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        Target target = new Target();
        target.setSubjectName( source.getCourseName() );
        return target;
    }
```

Now, my requirement is to prevent null check on `source` in MapStruct generated method. How can acheive that ?

Comment: A side question, why do you need to prevent the `null` check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to achieve that in the moment is to define your own custom `public Target map(Source source)` method. There is already an open issue for MapStruct to support the `@Nullable`, `@NonNull` annotations as well, but it still has not been done.

Comment: Could you link to the open issue so we can follow?

Comment: Probably https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1243

Answer (score 0):

```
@Mapping(target="subjectName", source="courseName",qualifiedByName = "yourCustomMethod")
Target map(Source source);

@Named("yourCustomMethod")
default Target yourCustomMethod(Source source){
if ( source == null ) {
        return null;
    }
    Target target = new Target();
    target.setSubjectName( source.getCourseName() );
    return target;
}
```

I call it copying from the compiler :D